# Getting the error "cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"" when I run code on Qt creator

Tags: c++11, makefile, qt-creator, qmake

I have taken the code from the following source on Github and am trying to run it from Qt on RHEL Red Hat 4.4.7-17:

https://github.com/neveraway/oclJPEGDecoder

I extracted the project folder and ran `qmake -project`in it. I opened the files in Qt creator and further modified my .pro file to link OpenCL sources and add the CXX and CFLAGS.

My .pro file looks like this:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (1.07a) Tue Mar 28 14:51:49 2017
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
DEPENDPATH += src \
              /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/

INCLUDEPATH += . src \
                /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/\
               /usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/
# Input
HEADERS += src/bitstream.h \
           src/bmp.h \
           src/decoder.h \
           src/huffman.h \
           src/idct.h \
           src/jpeg.h \
           src/macro.h \
           src/stdafx.h \
           src/targetver.h \
           src/zigzag.h

SOURCES += src/bitstream.cpp \
           src/cpuIDCT8x8.cpp \
           src/decoder.cpp \
           src/huffman.cpp \
           src/main.cpp \
           src/oclDCT8x8.cpp \
           src/parser.cpp \
           src/stdafx.cpp \
    src/main.cpp

LIBS += -L/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/ -lOpenCL

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=c99

DISTFILES += \
    src/idct8x8.cl \
    oclJPEGDecoder.sln \
    oclJPEGDecoder.vcxproj \
    oclJPEGDecoder.vcxproj.filters \
    README.md \
    test/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_050.jpg
```

When I clicked on `Run qmake` and then `Build All`, this is what I saw under "Compile Output":

```
18:08:23: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
18:08:23: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
Makefile:634: warning: overriding commands for target `main.o'
Makefile:603: warning: ignoring old commands for target `main.o'
g++ -c -pipe -std=c++11 -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../oclJPEGDecoder-master -I. -I../oclJPEGDecoder-master -I../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src -I/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64 -I/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o bitstream.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [bitstream.o] Error 1
18:08:23: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project oclJPEGDecoder-master (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.2 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
18:08:23: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

My `Makefile` has the following contents:

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: oclJPEGDecoder-master
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.6.2)
# Project:  ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/oclJPEGDecoder-master.pro
# Template: app
# Command: /opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/bin/qmake -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/oclJPEGDecoder-master.pro
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -std=c++11 -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I../oclJPEGDecoder-master -I. -I../oclJPEGDecoder-master -I../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src -I/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64 -I/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++
QMAKE         = /opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/bin/qmake
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = cp -f -R
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
DISTNAME      = oclJPEGDecoder-master1.0.0
DISTDIR = /root/Downloads/build-oclJPEGDecoder-master-Desktop_Qt_5_6_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/.tmp/oclJPEGDecoder-master1.0.0
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -L/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/ -lOpenCL -L/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Gui -L/usr/lib64 -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
AR            = ar cqs
RANLIB        = 
SED           = sed
STRIP         = strip
```

My `.o` files look like this:

```
####### Compile

bitstream.o: ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.cpp ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/targetver.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/macro.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o bitstream.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.cpp

cpuIDCT8x8.o: ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/cpuIDCT8x8.cpp ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/targetver.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/macro.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/idct.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o cpuIDCT8x8.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/cpuIDCT8x8.cpp

decoder.o: ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/decoder.cpp ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/targetver.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/macro.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/jpeg.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bmp.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/huffman.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/zigzag.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/idct.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o decoder.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/decoder.cpp

huffman.o: ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/huffman.cpp ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/targetver.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/macro.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/huffman.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o huffman.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/huffman.cpp

main.o: ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/main.cpp ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/targetver.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/macro.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/huffman.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/idct.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o main.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/main.cpp

oclDCT8x8.o: ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/oclDCT8x8.cpp ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/targetver.h \
        /usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/CL/opencl.h \
        /usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/CL/cl.h \
        /usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/CL/cl_platform.h \
        /usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/CL/cl_gl.h \
        /usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/CL/cl_gl_ext.h \
        /usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/CL/cl_ext.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/macro.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/idct.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o oclDCT8x8.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/oclDCT8x8.cpp

parser.o: ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/parser.cpp ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/targetver.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/macro.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/jpeg.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/decoder.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o parser.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/parser.cpp

stdafx.o: ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.cpp ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/targetver.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o stdafx.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.cpp

main.o: ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/main.cpp ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/stdafx.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/targetver.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/macro.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/huffman.h \
        ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/idct.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o main.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/main.cpp

####### Install

install:  FORCE

uninstall:  FORCE

FORCE:
```

**2nd ATTEMPT WITH `-std=c++0x`:**

I changed the CXX_FLAGS command to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x` and kept everything else unchanged in my `.pro` file. 
When I clicked on `Build All` after making the change, this is the output I got under "Compile Output":

```
18:38:06: Running steps for project oclJPEGDecoder-master...
18:38:06: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
18:38:06: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
Makefile:634: warning: overriding commands for target `main.o'
Makefile:603: warning: ignoring old commands for target `main.o'
g++ -c -pipe -std=c++0x -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../oclJPEGDecoder-master -I. -I../oclJPEGDecoder-master -I../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src -I/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64 -I/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o bitstream.o ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.cpp
In file included from ../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.cpp:4:
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:368: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:368: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member 'mBitReservoir'
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:368: error: making 'mBitReservoir' static
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:368: error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type 'uint8_t*'
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:369: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member 'mCapacity'
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:369: error: making 'mCapacity' static
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:369: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'mCapacity'
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'void BitStream::free()':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:96: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:96: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:98: error: type '<type error>' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'void BitStream::trim()':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:110: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'bool BitStream::reserve(size_t)':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:137: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'bool BitStream::frontBit() const':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:209: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'uint8_t BitStream::frontFullByte() const':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:214: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'uint32_t BitStream::front9b(uint8_t) const':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:219: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'uint32_t BitStream::front17b(uint8_t) const':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:227: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'uint32_t BitStream::front25b(uint8_t) const':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:235: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'void BitStream::writeBit(bool)':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:246: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:248: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'const uint8_t* BitStream::frontData() const':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:307: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'uint32_t BitStream::cachedFrontBits(int)':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:340: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h: In member function 'void BitStream::moveDataTo(uint8_t*)':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.h:398: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.cpp: In member function 'size_t BitStream::append(const uint8_t*, size_t)':
../oclJPEGDecoder-master/src/bitstream.cpp:22: error: 'mBitReservoir' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [bitstream.o] Error 1
18:38:06: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project oclJPEGDecoder-master (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.2 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
18:38:06: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

I got errors in `bitstream.c` due to incompatibility with the compiler.

**How can I get around this issue? Do I absolutely need to install a new version of g++ to get this code to work? Do I need to include anything in my `Makefile`?**

Please guide me in this matter.

EDIT:

My output for `g++ --version`:

```
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I typed `yum install rpmdevtools rpm-build` and it gave me the following response:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, search-disabled-repos, security,
              : subscription-manager
Setting up Install Process
Package rpmdevtools-7.5-2.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package rpm-build-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I wanted to obtain more information about gcc on my system so I typed this command:

```
yum list available |grep gcc
```

It gave me this response:

```
compat-gcc-34.x86_64              3.4.6-19.el6           rhel-6-workstation-rpms
compat-gcc-34-c++.x86_64          3.4.6-19.el6           rhel-6-workstation-rpms
compat-gcc-34-g77.x86_64          3.4.6-19.el6           rhel-6-workstation-rpms
gcc-gnat.x86_64                   4.4.7-18.el6           rhel-6-workstation-rpms
gcc-java.x86_64                   4.4.7-18.el6           rhel-6-workstation-rpms
gcc-objc.x86_64                   4.4.7-18.el6           rhel-6-workstation-rpms
gcc-objc++.x86_64                 4.4.7-18.el6           rhel-6-workstation-rpms
```

Comment: 4.4.7 is pretty old - try `-std=c++0x` instead of `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @aschepler Thank you for the response. I tried it already. I have even stated the output I got with that setting.

Comment: @aschepler It produced errors in a file called `bitstream.h`. I did not get the same errors with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: In your `Makefile`, you have `CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -std=c++011 -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)`. What is `-std=c++011` - just a copy/paste error?

Comment: @mtrw I did not add it. That statement was already there when I opened the `Makefile`. I added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` to my `.pro` file.

Comment: @mtrw That really was a typo. I have now added a new segment of the `Makefile`. It contains `c++11` in place of `c++011`.

Comment: @mtrw Despite the change, the errors I posted about have not been resolved.

Comment: Do I need to post the entire `Makefile`? It is fairly long so I figured I would only post the portions which I thought were problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 4.4.7 version of gcc is too old to fully enable C++11 features. 
You need to upgrade the compiler to a version superior to 4.6 ( at least ) or if it's possible for you, upgrade your distro (let's say RHEL 7) which includes a more recent compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which compiler version should I use? I read in [one of the answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125609/install-latest-gcc-on-rhel-6-x86-64) that doing so may break the system. Is this true?

Comment: You may use any C++11 compatible version of GCC you want but be careful not to break your system by replacing the default system version of libstdc++. You should install the new compiler and its dependancies in a separate directory, either from the sources or from the RH devtoolset which makes the process easier. However, depending on what your applications does, you should be very careful if you have to deploy your application on a fresh install of RH.

Comment: What is the location of libstdc++? I am new to this so please excuse me if my questions seem too basic.I tried to install from the toolset but it said the latest version is already installed.

Comment: I updated my question to include more information about my issues.